# If previous li has more height some white space is coming

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have some `<li>` that look like some list of boxes.

**screenshot**
[image]

**list**

```html
<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="1"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="2"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="3"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="4"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="5"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="6"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="7"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="8"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="9"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="10"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="11"></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="12"></li>
</ol>
```

**css**

```css
#selectable { 
      list-style-type: none; 
      margin: 0; 
      padding: 0; 
      width: 450px; 
}
#li .handle { 
      background: #f8f8f8; 
      position: absolute; 
      left: 0; 
      top: 0; 
      bottom: 0; 
      padding:8px; 
}
#selectable li { 
      margin: 3px; 
      padding: 1px; 
      float: left; 
      width: 100px; 
      height: 80px; 
      font-size: 4em; 
      text-align: center; 
}
```

Dynamically I will change the height of some `li` it messed up

See  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/fmusV/33/). Here i am merging selected boxes. Try selecting 4 and 8 you will see the issue.

**screenshot**
[image]

What I need is:

1. I want to fill the empty white spaces with **4** and **5**
2. Selection should be applicable only if boxes has same width(if vertical selection) and only boxes has same height (if horizontal selection)

Comment: Tried you `display:inline-block;`? The `li`s will behave like regular `div`s.

Comment: please see my updated question and fiddle

Comment: This is not a question, it's request to write your code for you. Alright, 1 could be a question if worded differently, but 2 simply is a request to do work for you...

Comment: Have you see my answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with masonry

[My codepen](http://codepen.io/ColoO/pen/jszdy) (it is one fork of the official example)

[Simple result](http://codepen.io/ColoO/pen/HsuFn) (without js button)

[Your jsfiddle modify](http://jsfiddle.net/kBjBc/9/) (when u click on apply. apply mansonry in var merge if u want result when u drag and drop)

HTML

```
<h1>Masonry - destroy</h1>
<p><button id="toggle-button">Toggle Masonry</button>
<ul class="masonry">

  <li class="item w2 h3">1</li >
  <li class="item w2 h3">2</li >
  <li class="item w2 h2">3</li >
  <li class="item w2 h3">4</li >
  <li class="item w2 h3">5</li >
  <li class="item w2 h3">6</li >

</ul>
```

JS

```
// http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js added as external resource

docReady( function() {

  var container = document.querySelector('.masonry');
  var button = document.querySelector('#toggle-button');
  var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    columnWidth: 200


 });

  var isActive = true;

  eventie.bind( button, 'click', function() {
    if ( isActive ) {
      msnry.destroy();
    } else {
      msnry = new Masonry( container );
    }
    isActive = !isActive;
  });

});
```

Comment: Hi ColoO,Thanks for your answer.In http://jsfiddle.net/kBjBc/9/
 I select the boxes and click "Apply" I am getting exactly what is required, but when I select other box for second time (without refreshing the screen) the whole layout is broken.It is half way done!! Please help me on this.

Comment: i don't understand what you want to do in your project but if you want add masonery when you drage and drop [http://jsfiddle.net/kBjBc/13/](http://jsfiddle.net/kBjBc/13/). you have always the same problem but the mansonery is alaways activated. You need to see where your code isn't compatible with masonery (i don't find :p maybe html syntaxe ? [masonery add property in style=""] )

Comment: finally, i can propose one [test](http://jsfiddle.net/kBjBc/15/). i press apply i start masonery, the second press "apply" destroy masonery. So before each action, you must remove masonery with this line msnry.destroy();. After u don't have bug. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like what you need is an [jQuery tile grid plugin](http://codegeekz.com/jquery-grids/). Don't think you'll be able to accomplish this only using HTML and CSS, unfortunately.

Comment: @NishamMahsin That didn't actually clarified anything, unfortunately. What's the fiddle soppose to do? Can you explain how your code works or what your trying to accomplish?

Comment: i am selecting boxes and merging selected boxes

Comment: @NishamMahsin Ah, now I understand! What you need to do then is to move the actual DOM elements around to the right order, so they float the right way to fill up the space.

Comment: .yes. when u merge 4 and 8 ,  the boxes 5,6,7,10,11,12 coming down. but i dont want this.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that know. Not sure you can accomplish this with a `<ul>` list and CSS. You might need to build it as a table and calculate the correct `colspan` and `rowspan` for each `<td>` on each merge. Needs a bit of thinking and code I admit. But the best solution I can think of right now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a list, I'm using a table to use `colspan` and `rowspan`. The JavaScript is fully commented, please ask if something is unclear.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XiozZe/fmusV/35/).

HTML:

```
<table id="selectable">
    <tr>
        <td class="xioCss" id="1">1</td>
        <td class="xioCss" id="2">2</td>
        <td class="xioCss" id="3">3</td>
        <td class="xioCss" id="4">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="xioCss" id="5">5</td>
        <td class="xioCss" id="6">6</td>
        <td class="xioCss" id="7">7</td>
        <td class="xioCss" id="8">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="xioCss" id="9">9</td>
        <td class="xioCss" id="10">10</td>
        <td class="xioCss" id="11">11</td>
        <td class="xioCss" id="12">12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#selectable {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px
}

.xioCss{
    width: 25%;
    height: 33%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px
}

#selectable .ui-selecting { 
    background: #FECA40; 
}

#selectable .ui-selected { 
    background: #F39814; 
    color: white; 
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
    filter: "td",
    stop: function(){
        var $selected = $(".ui-selected");

        if( $selected.length < 2 ){
            //Cannot combine when there are less than 2 selected
            return false;
        }

        //Remove strange acting hidden elements
        $selected.each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":hidden")){
                $selected = $selected.not($(this));
            }
        });

        //Save all the ids of the selected elements in an array
        var ids = $selected.map(function(){
            return parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
        }).get();     

        //Go through all the elements
        //and check if an element is hidden under one of the selected elements. 
        //If so, also select that element.
        var $allElements = $(".ui-selectee");       
        for (var i = 0; i < $allElements.length; i++){
            if(ids.indexOf($allElements[i].hiddenUnder) >= 0){
                $selected = $selected.add($allElements.eq(i));
            }
        }        

        //Comparing with the first td: vertical or horizontal
        var vertical = 0;
        var horizontal = 0;        
        for ( var i = 0; i < $selected.length; i++ ){
            //Checking: horizontal, has it the same tr as parent?
            if( $selected[0].parentNode === $selected[i].parentNode ){
                //Same tr as parent, so horizontal                
                horizontal++;
            }         

            //Checking: vertical, has it the same child index?
            if($selected.eq(0).index() === $selected.eq(i).index()){
                //Same child index, so vertical
                vertical++;
            }

        }

        //If the selected elements are a block, 
        //The product of horizontal and vertical should equal the amount of selected elements.
        if(horizontal*vertical !== $selected.length){
            return false;
        }


        //Hide all the td except the first on (skip 0), 
        //and save the element they are hidden under.
        for (var i = 1; i < $selected.length; i++){
            $selected.eq(i).hide();
            $selected[i].hiddenUnder = ids[0];
        }     

        //And set the colspan and the rowspan of the first one
        $selected.eq(0).attr({
            colspan: horizontal,
            rowspan: vertical
        });        
    }
})
```

Comment: Some second merges did indeed not work due to underestimated hidden elements, but they should be fully cooperating now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve this is to use the jquery plugin masonry.min.js
Its better to use the width in the percentage format rather than in fixed pixels.

Suppose you have a grid with 4 columns

```
<li class="item w1"> content 1 </li>
<li class="item w2"> content 2 </li>
<li class="item w3"> content 3 </li>
<li class="item w4"> content 4 </li>
```

CSS

```
.item { width:25%; }
.w1 { width:50%; }
.w2 { width:25%; }
.w3 { width:75%; }
.w4 { width:100%; }
```

Then the elements will be in the grid and number of elements in each row varies according to the width of the elements.